# Syntax for a Homebrew formula depending on a cask

Tags: macos, homebrew, osx-mountain-lion, homebrew-cask

I'm writing a homebrew formula for a project (https://www.cryfs.org).
Since it is a file system, it depends on osxfuse, which is unfortunately only available as a cask. That is, the formula should have the cask as a dependency.

I tried the following

```
depends_on :cask => "osxfuse"
```

but I got the error message

```
Unsupported special dependency :cask
```

What is the syntax for adding casks as dependencies to a formula?

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't find an answer to this problem either.

But as a poor mans **workaround** this serves well for the time being:

```
def install
  # Resolve cask dependencies
  system "/usr/local/bin/brew", "cask", "install", "osxfuse"
```

The big disadvantage is obvious, its not a so much of dependency relation than an installation command. Which may lead to problems until you actually install the package.

Answer (score -1):

Based on other formulas it seems like it needs to be `depends_on cask:` instead of `:cask`. There are multiple places where modules depend on a specific cask/macosx version and are defined as such: `depends_on macos: ""`. [Example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/master/Casks/genymotion.rb) of an cask dependency inside a cask formula.

```
depends_on cask: => "osxfuse"
```

Give me an heads up if it worked!

Comment: Sorry didn't work. depends_on cask: "osxfuse" is just a shorthand in the ruby language for depends_on :cask => "osxfuse". The example you posted is creating a cask, not a formula. I'd like a formula to depend on a cask.

Comment: Oh i see. I do not really have any ruby knowledge at all so i think i'm not able to help you out with this one, sorry.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried:

depends_on "caskroom/cask/osxfuse"